# Can't debug Spock test in IntelliJ

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, gradle, spock

I am trying to debug my Spock test in Gradle in IntelliJ with <kbd>ctrl+shift+d</kbd> (in other words: context menu -> debug).

But unfortunately it fails with following output:

```
Testing started at 12:13 ...
12:13:42: Executing external tasks 'cleanTest test --tests "com.***.MyTest.test1"
:cleanTest
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60991', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60991', transport: 'socket'
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
Process 'Gradle Test Executor 3' finished with non-zero exit value 134
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'Gradle Test Executor 3' finished with non-zero exit value 134
```

What is interesting, simple **run** of test is passing.
I am starting it on Mac, IntelliJ 15.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is unrelated to Spock. It seems that the debug port has problems.
Running the test does not use the debug port so of course it passes.

Close all applications, reboot and check to see if port 60991 is really free. 
Also check that you do not have a personal firewall that blocks this port.

Comment: Every time I call tests the selected port is different. But I could check with firewall

Comment: Nope, me firewall is turned off

Comment: Searching for "JDWP No transports initialized" in Google show up about 7-10 similar stackoverflow actions. All of them deal with network problems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644690/impossible-to-run-web-application-in-debug-mode-with-intellij-on-ubuntu-with-gla