# Glassfish The server exited prematurely with exit code 134

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

I have Glassfish server v4.1 with the default port configuration, debug mode suddenly stopped working with the following error message ::

```
The server exited prematurely with exit code 134.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
```

I listed all the open ports on my machine, but couldn't find the debug port used anywhere. I tried to changed the port but the same error still there.

I used the following commands to list open ports::

```
sockstat -l | grep 9009 
lsof -l | grep 9009
ss -l | grep 9009
```

I have java 1.7 (Oracle JDK) installed on OpenSuse tumbleweed.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for other clues, seems the problem wasn't in the port but the other debug options in the domain.xml file, specifically the following line

```
<java-config debug-options="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=9009" system-classpath="" classpath-suffix="">
```

Changed to

```
<java-config debug-options="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009" system-classpath="" classpath-suffix="">
```

fixed the problem, Thanks to the answer of the following question ::
[Impossible to run web application in debug mode with intelliJ on ubuntu with glassfish server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14669478/6473975)